# Understanding AWS pricing for MySQL RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am looking into AWS RDS for MySQL pricing.

When I create a database using their EasyCreate option, one of the options is the following for **$2.078/hour** (about $1,500 / month).

- db.r5.xlarge
- 4 vCPUs
- 32 GiB RAM
- 500 GiB

However, when I look on the pricing chart https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/pricing/, it tells me that the db.r5.xlarge costs **$0.48/hour** on demand (about $345/month) and even less if paid up front.

The 500 GiB storage is $115 per month even with multi-AZ deployment.

I realize there can be some differences based on the chosen region, but not anywhere near that much.

What costs am I missing?

Comment: Which region, and Multi-AZ?

Comment: West, Oregon. Even with multi-AZ, the 500 GB still only adds $115/month according to the pricing calculator.

Comment: What does backup look like?

Comment: The EasyCreate option says that automatic backup is enabled. That's all it says about backups.

Comment: Right, let me just check for you

Comment: I have confirmed with the Amazon RDS console team that this calculation is incorrect (it was double-counting for Multi-AZ) and they will correct it in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this a UI bug and it has now been fixed in the Amazon RDS console:

[image: Amazon RDS price]

Answer (score 0):

I have had a go at creating this in the console and can confirm that the configuration matches below

[image: Configuration of Easy Create]

It also comes with 7 days of backup retention. Considering that some options do not even have a price for them with (Oracle and SQL Server) at this point in time, I am inclined to believe there is not any additional pricing.

Saying that I would recommend creating outside of the "Easy Create" view for a production DB.

Comment: What does the price come to there? It's starneg that the EasyCreate option is so much more expensive

Comment: I am presuming free text, the price itself matches very closely that of an RDS instance double the size. If you check SQL Server and Oracle you can see neither of those have prices so there must be something configured differently there